# PowerShell, Pulling out multiple arrays from an variable to make a single variable

Tags: arrays, powershell, variables, hashtable

I have a variable `$metrics`, and for the lack of knowing for sure, I am calling this an Array of Arrays? I'm probably wrong, but its best I can think of.

Here is the variable.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $metrics


Id         : cpuUtil01
Label      : CPUUtilization
Messages   : {}
StatusCode : Complete
Timestamps : {11/27/2021 7:00:00 PM, 11/27/2021 7:05:00 PM, 11/27/2021 7:10:00 PM, 11/27/2021 7:15:00 PM...}
Values     : {51.22, 31.3833333333333, 31.4116666666667, 31.5283333333333...}
```

I want to pull the `$metrics.timestamps` and `$metrics.values` out so I can export them into a CSV file, so I can use Excel's Line Graph. I can't figure out how to pull out the two of them into one variable.

I can do it one at a time, like below, but how do I join them so I have a CSV I can use.

```
$o = ""
$out = @()

foreach ($GetMetric in $Metrics.timestamps){ 

$o = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property  ([ordered]@{
            
            TimeStampUTC = $GetMetric;
                        
                           })
$out += $o

}
$out

TimeStampUTC          
------------          
11/27/2021 7:00:00 PM 
11/27/2021 7:05:00 PM 
11/27/2021 7:10:00 PM 
11/27/2021 7:15:00 PM 
11/27/2021 7:20:00 PM 
11/27/2021 7:25:00 PM 
11/27/2021 7:30:00 PM 
11/27/2021 7:35:00 PM 
11/27/2021 7:40:00 PM 
11/27/2021 7:45:00 PM
```

```
$o = ""
$out = @()

foreach ($GetMetric in $Metrics.values){ 

$o = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property  ([ordered]@{
            
            Values = $GetMetric;
                        
                           })
$out += $o

}
$out

          Values
          ------
           51.22
31.3833333333333
31.4116666666667
31.5283333333333
31.4166666666667
          31.425
31.4916666666667
31.4166666666667
          31.325
31.5916666666667
```

What I would like to have is a variable that has both values, and looks like below, so I can output it to a csv file.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $output

TimeStampUTC              Values
------------              ------
11/27/2021 7:00:00 PM     51.22
11/27/2021 7:05:00 PM     31.3833333333333
11/27/2021 7:10:00 PM     31.4116666666667
11/27/2021 7:15:00 PM     31.5283333333333
11/27/2021 7:20:00 PM     31.4166666666667
11/27/2021 7:25:00 PM     31.425
11/27/2021 7:30:00 PM     31.4916666666667
11/27/2021 7:35:00 PM     31.4166666666667
11/27/2021 7:40:00 PM     31.325
11/27/2021 7:45:00 PM     31.5916666666667
```

How would you do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

-Rugbyball

<edited - additional notes>

Here was my output for the .GetType() and Get-Member

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $metrics.GeTtype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                          
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                          
True     True     List`1                                   System.Object                                                                                                     



PS C:\Windows\system32> $metrics.Values.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                          
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                          
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array                                                                                                      



PS C:\Windows\system32> $metrics | Get-Member


   TypeName: Amazon.CloudWatch.Model.MetricDataResult

Name        MemberType Definition                                                                              
----        ---------- ----------                                                                              
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                          
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()                                                                       
GetType     Method     type GetType()                                                                          
ToString    Method     string ToString()                                                                       
Id          Property   string Id {get;set;}                                                                    
Label       Property   string Label {get;set;}                                                                 
Messages    Property   System.Collections.Generic.List[Amazon.CloudWatch.Model.MessageData] Messages {get;set;}
StatusCode  Property   Amazon.CloudWatch.StatusCode StatusCode {get;set;}                                      
Timestamps  Property   System.Collections.Generic.List[datetime] Timestamps {get;set;}                         
Values      Property   System.Collections.Generic.List[double] Values {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is usually known as *"merge arrays"* or *"join arrays"*. There are many ways to approach this, for example, with a [`for`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-7.2) loop.

To answer your first question, `$metrics` is an [`object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=net-6.0), and as any object it can have properties and methods. In this case, your `object` has 3 properties which are [`arrays`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=net-6.0). To give some perspective on how you can approach this in the future, it's key to know about the [`.GetType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=net-6.0) method and [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-7.2).

This is a recreation of your object using [`[PSCustomObject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.2):

```
$metrics = [pscustomobject]@{
    Id         = 'cpuUtil01'
    Label      = 'CPUUtilization'
    Messages   = @()
    StatusCode = 'Complete'
    Timestamps = '11/27/2021 7:00:00 PM','11/27/2021 7:05:00 PM','11/27/2021 7:10:00 PM'
    Values     = '51.22','31.3833333333333','31.4116666666667','31.5283333333333'
}
```

Now we can put it into practice:

```
PS /> $metrics.GeTtype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name             BaseType
-------- -------- ----             --------
True     False    PSCustomObject   System.Object

PS /> $metrics.Values.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name             BaseType
-------- -------- ----             --------
True     True     Object[]         System.Array

PS /> $metrics | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
Id          NoteProperty string Id=cpuUtil01
Label       NoteProperty string Label=CPUUtilization
Messages    NoteProperty Object[] Messages=System.Object[]
StatusCode  NoteProperty string StatusCode=Complete
Timestamps  NoteProperty Object[] Timestamps=System.Object[]
Values      NoteProperty Object[] Values=System.Object[]
```

---

Now to answer the main question, *how to merge both arrays?*:

- First we need to know if both have the same `length`, else we would be losing information:

```
$maxCount = [math]::Max($metrics.TimeStamps.Count, $metrics.Values.Count)
```

Then just loop over each element of each array using a `for` loop creating a new object out of their values:

```
$result = for($i = 0; $i -lt $maxCount; $i++)
{
    [pscustomobject]@{
        TimeStamps = $metrics.TimeStamps[$i]
        Values = $metrics.Values[$i]
    }
}
```

```
PS /> $result

TimeStamps            Values
----------            ------
11/27/2021 7:00:00 PM 51.22
11/27/2021 7:05:00 PM 31.3833333333333
11/27/2021 7:10:00 PM 31.4116666666667
11/27/2021 7:15:00 PM 31.5283333333333
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, and thank you for the information on what I was working with. I strive to learn something new everyday!

Here was my output for the

Comment: @Rugbyball happy to help and glad you could learn something new :)

Comment: I edited the question to include my .GetType() and Get-Member.

Only difference in mine to yours was in `$metrics.GeTtype()`  mine was `True` for `IsSerial` where yours was `False`  Not sure if that changes anything or not. Just happened to notice it.

Comment: Also, not a biggie, picked it up right away. But for any other following along. i noticed a typo in one line.
`$maxCount = [math]::Max($matrics.TimeStamps.Count, $metrics.Values.Count)`
Should be
`$maxCount = [math]::Max($metrics.TimeStamps.Count, $metrics.Values.Count)`
Again, no biggie, just pointing out for others who may use this.
Thanks again `Santiago Squarzon`

Comment: @Rugbyball Good catch, thanks for pointing that out. I'll edit my answer. `IsSerial` comes from [`Type.IsSerializable Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isserializable?view=net-6.0)